# Preserve whitespaces in variable and exchange with SED

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I already read dozens of articles but I couldn't find a working solution so far.

I need to exchange 6 coordinates in a textfile, which is formated as a LS-Dyna input - the fields are identified by columns of 10 digits where the content has to be right-aligned in the columns:

I start with something like this (the content of the file "test.txt"):

```
*DEFINE_BOX_TITLE
Anonymous BOX Card
$234567890      
$    BOXID       XMN       XMX       YMN       YMX       ZMN       ZMX
%box%
$
```

Desired final result looks like this (should be stored in test2.txt):

```
*DEFINE_BOX_TITLE
Anonymous BOX Card
$234567890      
$    BOXID       XMN       XMX       YMN       YMX       ZMN       ZMX
%   807777      2458      3658     -1056       144       552      1752
$
```

My script so far:

```
#!/bin/tcsh 
###


set boxid = 807777
set xmin = 2458
set xmax = 3658
set ymin = -1056
set ymax = 144
set zmin = 552
set zmax = 1752


set box = `echo "$boxid $xmin $xmax $ymin $ymax $zmin $zmax" | awk '{printf("%-1s%9d%10d%10d%10d%10d%10d%10d\n","%",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)}'`

echo  "$box"

cat test.txt | sed "s/%box%/$box/g" > test2.txt
```

**My Problem:**

The necessary blanks in the variable "box" vanish, the output looks like this:

```
% 807777 2458 3658 -1056 144 552 1752
```

...and not like this:

```
%   807777      2458      3658     -1056       144       552      1752
```

Can you guys come up with an idea how to do that?

I'd really appreciate any hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf` instead of `awk`:

```
#!/bin/tcsh 
###

set boxid = 807777
set xmin = 2458
set xmax = 3658
set ymin = -1056
set ymax = 144
set zmin = 552
set zmax = 1752

set box = "`printf '%%%9s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n' \
                   $boxid $xmin $xmax $ymin $ymax $zmin $zmax`"

echo  "$box"

sed "s/%box%/$box/g" test.txt > test2.txt
```

Run that, and the contents of *test2.txt* are:

```
*DEFINE_BOX_TITLE
Anonymous BOX Card
$234567890      
$    BOXID       XMN       XMX       YMN       YMX       ZMN       ZMX
%   807777      2458      3658     -1056       144       552      1752
$
```

Comment: :0 Wow, that works perfectly....

Unfortunately, I have a long tcsh-script where I want to implement this part, I cannot rewrite the whole thing. Any chance to solve it with tcsh?

Thanks!

Comment: @LukasH, Re *"with tcsh"*: see revised answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't quite understand why it's working but it does!

Comment: @LukasH, It's white-space quoting thing.  Using `tcsh`, try this `set x = "\`printf '%s\t%s\n' foo bar\`" ; echo "$x"`, and note that *"foo"* and *"bar"* are tab `\t` separated.  Now try `set x = \`printf '%s\t%s\n' foo bar\` ; echo "$x"`, or even `set x = "\`printf '%s\t%s\n' foo bar\`" ; echo $x`, and observe that the `\t` is displayed as a space.

Comment: thank you, I tried it and I get it now :)  Before, I was just trying out different ways until sth. worked, now I can work more straight forward.